# Semantic-UI Modal causes my element to disappear from the DOM after closing

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Really simple question here...note the code snippet first:

```
$('#gasmask').on('click', function(){
      $('#gasmask').modal('show');
 });
```

Clicking the element with an ID of `gasmask` causes the Semantic-UI modal to show, quite nicely. The issue is that after I click away, causing the modal to disappear, so the does the original element...

Before click:

```
<div class="content">
    <img alt="Gasmask" class="fademein3 ui image" id="gasmask"    src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/verumdesigns/gasmask.jpg" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1;">
</div>
```

After modal closes:

```
<div class="content">

</div>
```

It just straight up vanishes from the DOM. What's the dealio?

Comment: have you tried something like `$('#gasmask').on('blur', function(){  $('#gasmask').modal('hide'); });`?

Comment: Just tried that, didn't help, I noticed that the element didn't totally vanish from the DOM actually. It got moved outside of <div class="pusher">.

Answer (score 2):

Semantic UI moves the modal contents around in the DOM, as you have figured out.  I believe this is so that the modal gets the appropriate inherited styling to display as intended, rather than inherit whichever "component" embeds the modal.

There is an option called "detachable", which you could use like such:

```
  $('.modal')
    .modal({
      detachable: false
    })
    .modal('show')
```

This would ensure that your model contents stay where they are.  This has hardly ever been a good option for me, because the modal inherits the styling I use for the component that embeds the modal, which just mucks up the modal.  Maybe there is a way to prevent that with CSS?

If CSS can't come to the rescue, then it's up to redesign your frontend. 
 For me, that meant turning the modal into a singleton component that I can instantiate from another component, passing whichever values are needed to display the modal.  Obviously details on that will differ on whether you are using Riot, React, Angular, ...

Another option, if you only have one modal and you don't care where it lives in your DOM, is to id your element with the HTML id attribute.  That way you don't care where it is relative to your component.